# Azure AD B2C - Not redirecting to SignIn/SignUp Page(login.microsoftonline.com...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a project that I have started building, and want to make us of Azure AD B2C - I have followed some tutorials and tested by creating a new MVC app from scratch and I got it working, however, when I try implement it into my existing project, then it does not redirect to the SignIn/SignUp page(this is the login.microsoftonline.com...) url. I know my code works to redirect to this url as it worked on the new project I created to test, so just not sure why it wont on my existing project.

This is in my Web.Config:

```
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="Name.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="GUID" />
<add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="Secret" />
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44382/" />
<add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_SiUpIn" />
<add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="B2C_1_SiPe" />
<add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="B2C_1_SSPR" />
```

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sign up / Sign in", "SignUpSignIn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "signUpSignInLink" })
```

This is the SignUpSignIn function I am calling:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public void SignUpSignIn()
        {
            // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
                return;
            }

            Response.Redirect("/");
        }
```

Below is the code from my Startup:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        // App config settings
        public static string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        public static string ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        public static string AadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
        public static string Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
        public static string RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        public static string ServiceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:TaskServiceUrl"];

        // B2C policy identifiers
        public static string SignUpSignInPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];
        public static string EditProfilePolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:EditProfilePolicyId"];
        public static string ResetPasswordPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId"];

        public static string DefaultPolicy = SignUpSignInPolicyId;

        // API Scopes
        public static string ApiIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ApiIdentifier"];
        public static string ReadTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ReadScope"];
        public static string WriteTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:WriteScope"];
        public static string[] Scopes = new string[] { ReadTasksScope, WriteTasksScope };

        // OWIN auth middleware constants
        public const string ObjectIdElement = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";

        // Authorities
        public static string Authority = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy);

        /*
        * Configure the OWIN middleware 
        */
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                    MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

                    // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                    ClientId = ClientId,
                    RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,

                    // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    },

                    // Specify the claims to validate
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name"
                    },

                    // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                    Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {ReadTasksScope} {WriteTasksScope}"
                }
            );
        }

        /*
         *  On each call to Azure AD B2C, check if a policy (e.g. the profile edit or password reset policy) has been specified in the OWIN context.
         *  If so, use that policy when making the call. Also, don't request a code (since it won't be needed).
         */
        private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(DefaultPolicy))
            {
                notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId;
                notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken;
                notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        /*
         * Catch any failures received by the authentication middleware and handle appropriately
         */
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();

            // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page 
            // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
            if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
            }
            else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
            {
                notification.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }


        /*
         * Callback function when an authorization code is received 
         */
        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            // Extract the code from the response notification
            var code = notification.Code;

            string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
            ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Handle
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on this ActionLink it hits the controller but then does not redirect, it just returns this URL:

https://localhost:44382/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2faccount%2fsignupsignin

One thing I must mention, is I purchased a template that I am using - Dont know if this might have any effect - I am completely stumped and dont know what else I can look at....

If you need anything that I have not posted, please let me know.

If anyone is able to assist me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your startup code for configuring auth?  [Reference sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the Startup code now.

Comment: np.  did that work?

Comment: Having a look at what you provided and what I have, it looks about the same. So my issue still exists

Comment: Having a look at the link you sent, this is the exact project I used actually. So my issue still exists unfortunately.

Comment: Darn.  can you put a breakpoint on `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`.  is that getting hit?

Comment: Hmm it isnt... Any idea why ?

Comment: I landed up creating a brand new project and moved the items from the template I bought(which was an mvc project) to the newly created project. Pain in the but, but it ended up working. There was obviously something in the bought template that was causing the issue.

Comment: @AxleWack, good to hear you've resolved this. Can you post your findings as an answer and flag the question as answered?

Comment: Done. Not sure if it will really help anyone, but perhaps it leads them to do the same thing if experiencing something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately I didnt find a specific solution to FIX the problem, as I could not pin point what exactly the problem was. However, I did sort out the problem by creating a brand new project and moved the items from the template I bought(which was an mvc project) to the newly created project. Pain in the butt as I needed to fix any bugs that occurred because of this, but it ended up working. There was obviously something in the bought template that was causing the issue.

So just to give some context - The template I bought had different frameworks you could use(MVC, PHP, Angular etc.), and I used the MVC project that contained the template and I just carried on building on that MVC project, so I am assuming there was something within that project that was causing the problem.